# Order by subquery column value

Tags: sql, subquery

I want to order an SQL query according to a subquery table.

- TABLE books (id, name, author, date)
- TABLE user (id, name, created)
- table books_likes (user_id, book_id, date)

My query for selecting each liked book. I want it ordered by books_likes.date, not using a join but an easier to index subquery

First attempt:

```
SELECT id 
FROM books 
WHERE id IN (SELECT book_id 
             FROM books_likes 
             WHERE user_id = 1) 
ORDER BY books_likes.date
```

Second attempt:

```
SELECT id 
FROM books 
WHERE id IN (SELECT book_id 
             FROM books_likes 
             WHERE user_id = 1 
             ORDER BY date)
```

None of these is working. The column isn't found (first attempt) or I get an error in my syntax (second attempt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `WHERE IN + subquery` approach is that it can only limit the records in the `books` table, but it can't make use of the columns inside the `books_likes` table.

I would phrase your query using a join:

```
SELECT
    b.id
FROM books b
INNER JOIN books_likes bl
    ON b.id = bl.book_id
WHERE
    bl.user_id = 1
ORDER BY
    bl.date;
```

The following index might help the above query, if MySQL choose to use it:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON books_likes (user_id, book_id, date);
```

Comment: How would the indices look to make the query efficient when having too many entries?

Comment: @MarcusDrews I gave you an index option which might help your query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `join` at all.  You should try:

```
SELECT bl.book_id
FROM books_likes bl
WHERE bl.user_id = 1
ORDER BY bl.date;
```

This query should use an index on `books_likes(user_id, date, book_id)`.